# PHP get value of one column in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm writing some data off my MySQL database into an array using columns with php like this:

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $row->id = $row["ID"];
            $row->product = $row["product"];
            $row->aantal = $row["Aantal"];
            $row->price = $row["Price"];
            $od[] = $row;
    }
    } else {
       echo "0 results";
    }
```

now later I have to use the $row->id and $row->product of the different columns seperatly to get some more data out of another table in MySQL. I've been trying to accomplish this:

```
$to = 0;
foreach($od as $odt)
{
    $odb= $odt[$to]["ID"];
    $sql = "SELECT `Name` FROM `detail` WHERE `ID` = '$odb'";
    $to++;
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I've tried dozen of others but can't seem to get this thing right...

Any solutions or remarks?

EDIT:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [product] => 10 [Aantal] => 1 [Price] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [product] => 13 [Aantal] => 1 [Price] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => 5 [product] => 3 [Aantal] => 3 [Price] => 4 ) )

Comment: you have unnecessarily overwritten your array into an object, and you don't need a foreach if you're going to point to the first element directly. and that `$to` is also unneeded, you just made your foreach loop more complicated

Comment: Abhik answer should get it working, however you should look into SQL joins. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: I am familiar with SQL joins but I don't understand how they can be of help to this matter? I will still have to check the matching id's to get the required data out of my db and to do so I have to get these values out of that array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, you are saving object in an array and trying the get the data with array, it should be as

```
foreach($od as $key=>$odt)
{
    $odb= $odt->id;
    $sql = "SELECT `Name` FROM `detail` WHERE `ID` = '$odb'";
}
```

Comment: I'm getting: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Check `print_r($od)` if there are some data in the array before doing the loop. more over you are using the same variable name `row` inside the first loop, if you want this way choose some other name `$row_data = new stdClass ;` and store like `$row_data->id = $row["ID"]`

Comment: There is data in the array

Comment: if you want this way choose some other name `$row_data = new stdClass ;` and store like `$row_data->id = $row["ID"]`

Comment: Although while assigning the $row->id = $row[ID]; etc I'm getting: Attempt to assign property of non-object in

Comment: Your last comment fixed my above error but I'm still getting the trying to get property of non object

Comment: Do a `print_r` of the final array and share it to the question.

Comment: Edited as requested above

Comment: Looks like you are doing `$od[] = $row;` you need to do as `$od[] = $row_data;` as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Executing queries in a loop is not advisable.  This answer should not be put into practice and the question deserves a re-think.